# Regular expression for maximum value

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have come up with the following regexp to accept values with a .25 interval or in quarter format, like 1.25, 10.75, 11.50, 12, 13.

*Regular Expression*

```
^\d+((\.0+)*|(\.250*)|(\.50*)|(\.750*))$
```

> Example
>
> **Accepted Values** = 0, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 3 , 1.25 , 1.50, 1.75, 5 , 10
>
> **Not Accepted Values** = 0.15, 0.20, 0.26, 0.30, 1.30, 1.55

I have the following questions;

1. How can I make it not accept .25, but accept 0.25?
2. How can I limit the value to the maximum number? I want it to accept up to 15.5.

Comment: if you are doing `1/4` inch increments how come you can't check the value to see if it's greater > `15.5` what's preventing you from writing some conditional check

Comment: `if (f > 0 && f % 0.25 == 0 && f <= 15.5)`

Comment: `if (inches % .25 < 0) && inches  < 15.5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the ***wrong*** way to do this, but a solution nonetheless:

```
^((1[0-4]|[0-9])?(\.(25|5|75)?0*)?|15(\.(25|5)?0*)?)$
```

#### [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/pQ0rR4/6)

```
Regex r = new Regex("^((1[0-4]|[0-9])?(\\.(25|5|75)?0*)?|15(\\.(25|5)?0*)?)$");
string[] arr = {".25", "17.545", "3.75000", "19.5", "10.500", "0.25"};

foreach(string s in arr) {
    if (r.IsMatch(s)) {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

It gives:

```
.25
3.75000
10.500
0.25
```

Comment: @user1263981 - it's not... Follow the link and enter it into the window

Comment: one more question, how can i change it to accept max 4.5?

Comment: Change `(1[0-4]|[0-9])` to `([0-3])` and `15` to `4`

Comment: for max 24 would be ^((2[0-3]|1[0-9]|[0-9])?(\.(0|25|5|75)0*)?|24(\.(0)0*)?)$

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion, Regex is not the correct tool for that kind of work. All the values you want to accept are decimal values. Simply parse the entered value as decimal and then check if it's correct regarding your accepted values:

```
decimal number;

if (Decimal.TryParse(value, out number))
   // Check if you're in the correct range
```

It will be much simpler, and errorproof.

Comment: all your accepted values are decimal, at least from your question. The TryParse will fail, and return false, if the value is not Decimal, so you know if it returns true it's already a good format.

Comment: @user1263981 How can a multiple of .25 that's < 15.5 *not* be representable as a decimal?

Answer (score 0):

I think Regex is the wrong way to do it, but if you insist then the following should suit you right.

```
^(\d|1[0-5]?)((\.0+)*|(\.250*)|(\.50*)|(\.750*))$
```

Comment: This doesn't match `.25`

Comment: @arco444, Right, and it shouldn't. It should match `0.25` and it does.

Comment: OP's Question 1 suggests otherwise to me? It also matches `15.75`

Comment: I didn't accepted that as a value for the first place. Probably skipped that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not accepting .25 as if you have a `\d+` at the beginning which means that you are waiting at least one digital before `"."`.  I think you could change `\d+` by the following `(0|1)?[1-5]?` to accept till 15.

Regex details can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Sorry for mistyping. Modified * by ?

Comment: @Anna Now it won't match `9`

Comment: @arco444 I could no post under you answer but it seems to me that it's not matching whole numbers like 1 2 ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^((?:1[0-4]|[0-9])?(?:\.(?:25|5|75))?0*|15(?:\.(?:25|5)?0*)?)$
```

**Demo:** http://regex101.com/r/eQ2pA1/7

Comment: Matches `51894.0000` which is > 15

Comment: Matches `15.75` which is > 15.5

Comment: Doesn't match `8.250`

Comment: Now this work correctly, but I think problem solved ;) that's good.

Answer (score 0):

`^(0|1)?[1-4]?(|\.0+|\.250*|\.50*|\.750*)$` for matching 0-14 numbers and make a | to match with numbers 15, 15.25, 15.50* with the following:

`15(|\.0+|\.250*|\.50*)`

The final one will be

`^(((0|1)?[1-4]?(|\.0+|\.250*|\.50*|\.750*)) | (15(|\.0+|\.250*|\.50*)))$`